# Keyboard navigation on a Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard

I've started to use a Mac recently, and what I'm missing a lot is Windows keyboard GUI navigation. You know, Tab, left, right, enter and space. On Windows I could install an application without ever touching the mouse.

On a Mac, as far as I understand, you could move in such a manner only between text boxes: no check boxes or radio buttons, no buttons.

Am I right? Is there a Macintosh way to control the OS from a keyboard?

Comment: Yeah, learn all the shortcuts. With Quicksilver installed the only time I really have to use the mouse is in Photoshop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable extended keyboard control in System Preferences->Keyboard & Mouse->Keyboard Shortcuts and select the "All controls"-radiobutton in the "Full keyboard access"-section in the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: Correct, but that option, for me, makes navigating a nightmare. Enable it and then try to use Tab in Mail or in Firefox... (Well, Safari uses Option-Tab rather than just Tab to step through links, so behaves better than Firefox.) And with or without that option enabled, in dialogs you just never know if Command-letter will let you press a button.